# Can't connect dvi hdmi to LG tv

Tags: 14.04, display, macbook

I have a 2009 macbook with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
somehow my LG tv doesn't recognize the DVI to HDMI.
Is there some driver i need to install by the way I'm completely new to Linux 
thank you for your help. I didn't have a problem before on mac lion but only because i was using a program called switchers.

I have tried system settings-> display and do not see an HDMI option

Answer (score 0):

DVI-A requires an analogue to digital conversion in the cable. Only DVI-D can be a flush fit straight to HDMI. Have you taken this into consideration? Are you using the appropriate cables for the correct ports?